# hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, dialect

I am new to hibernate and i was wondering if someone can help me out on this.I tried all the dialect but i cant figure it out. please help

when i run simple java using hibernate to store data to a table...`Feb 20, 2015 3:12:19 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 20, 2015 3:12:19 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 20, 2015 3:12:19 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1827)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1785)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
    at org.mikias.kidane.hi.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:18)`

here is my hibernate.cfg.xml code

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/konohashop</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pass</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="org.m.mi.UserDetails"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is **hibernate.dialect** check below once.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      root123
   </property>

   <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="org.m.mi.UserDetails"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: i still getting the same error..i don't know how. It's been days to figure out this error

Comment: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set this shows that it should be hibernate.dialect, what error you are getting now?